# Thymeleaf error resolving template while build as a docker container

Tags: spring-boot, docker, spring-mvc, docker-compose, thymeleaf

My spring boot application can't resolve template. Here is the error

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [Sharing/sharingBootStrap], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers (template: "Sharing/home" - line 10, col 10)
2021-11-21T18:22:22.207974004Z  at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.resolveTemplate(TemplateManager.java:869) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.207976849Z  at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseStandalone(TemplateManager.java:250) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.207979565Z  at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.FragmentExpression.resolveExecutedFragmentExpression(FragmentExpression.java:588) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.207982345Z  at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardFragmentInsertionTagProcessor.computeFragment(AbstractStandardFragmentInsertionTagProcessor.java:379) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.207985126Z  at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardFragmentInsertionTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractStandardFragmentInsertionTagProcessor.java:110) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.207988013Z  at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.207990763Z  at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.207994100Z  at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208016966Z  at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1314) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208028148Z  at org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208031134Z  at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateModel.process(TemplateModel.java:136) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208033712Z  at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:661) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208036384Z  at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208038955Z  at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208041643Z  at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:362) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208044371Z  at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208047543Z  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1373) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208050216Z  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1118) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208052890Z  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208055578Z  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208058270Z  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208060957Z  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208063635Z  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:4.0.FR]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208066701Z  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208069599Z  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:4.0.FR]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208072240Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208074931Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208077621Z  at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208080193Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208084927Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208087713Z  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.4.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208090373Z  at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.4.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208093093Z  at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.4.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208095848Z  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.4.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208098504Z  at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.4.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208101167Z  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.4.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208104281Z  at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.4.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208107023Z  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.4.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208109776Z  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.4.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208112509Z  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.4.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208115223Z  at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.4.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208117961Z  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.4.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208120621Z  at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.4.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208123343Z  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.4.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208126008Z  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.doFilterInternal(DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.java:52) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.4.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208128770Z  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208133348Z  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.4.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208136162Z  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:216) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.4.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208139199Z  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.4.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208142002Z  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.4.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208144844Z  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.4.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208147600Z  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.4.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208150338Z  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.4.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208153081Z  at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.4.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208155826Z  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208158541Z  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.4.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208161235Z  at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.4.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208163936Z  at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.4.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208166656Z  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208169353Z  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.4.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208172231Z  at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.4.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208174988Z  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.4.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208177662Z  at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.4.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208182152Z  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208184909Z  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.4.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208187591Z  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.4.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208190318Z  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.4.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208193024Z  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208195718Z  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208198370Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208201042Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208203621Z  at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208206299Z  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208209164Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208211855Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208214519Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208217114Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208219706Z  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208222356Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208225014Z  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208227589Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208232351Z  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208235023Z  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208237610Z  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208240219Z  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208242890Z  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208245456Z  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208248003Z  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208250664Z  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208253238Z  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
2021-11-21T18:22:22.208256152Z  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
```

During exploring the issue I have found that it can be solved by something like this.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry){
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/templates/");
    }
}
```

Unfortunetly it didn't help.
Here is how structure looks.
[image]

Here below I put my dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:11-jdk
COPY target/ddco-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ddco-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/ddco-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

and docker-compose

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  docker-mysql-db-rel-mvc:
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=mvc
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
  my-web-app-mvc:
    build:
      context: ""
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://docker-mysql-db-rel-mvc:3306/mvc
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: root
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: root
    depends_on:
      - docker-mysql-db-rel-mvc
    links:
      - docker-mysql-db-rel-mvc
```

I have no idea what I can do more.
Is there a way to fix that in docker-compose file or by spring boot app ?

Comment: Everything works if it is not build as a container.

Comment: Ditch the `WebConfiguration` class. It breaks auto configuration and adds nothing over the default settings (it actyually might even break those). I also wonder your container uses Linux, are you locally on windows? As `Sharing/home` is case sensitive.